# Monitoring webapp deployed in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, monitoring, jmx

From a webapp deployed in a Glassfish app server, I have to find some metrics to allow monitoring.
Inside the webapp, is there others tools/libraries which allow me to gather such metrics ?

I know I can connect to JMX/AMX, but is there others solutions ?

Answer (score 2):

[JavaMelody](http://javamelody.googlecode.com) can monitor a lot of things inside the webapp (used memory, %cpu, http sessions, ...), and if you want that you could use it to access metrics and JMX values over just http.

Answer (score 0):

dpending on your client there is variety of options - first comming to my mind is JSON or CSV provided through HTTP URL you can pull

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Codahale Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/) library which provides you a conevient way to collect many different metrics. Furthermore it provides different reporters as JMX, CSV, JSON, fileoutput.